# error : data argument not used by format string in url writing

Tags: ios

here i have making constant.h file:
code is :

```
#define ip @"some ip"
#define urlString @"@/icancer/webservice_iphone/@"
#define ws_typesOfCancer @"typesOfCancerDisplay.php"
```

and in my .m file string formated is:-

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:urlString,ip,ws_typesOfCancer];
```

error in str line...how this solve...

Comment: before each '@' in the format string add '%'

Comment: If you want to use the String as URL, `ip` should be indeed an IP (or host name).

Comment: Note: You should use `NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:` and related methods for building paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your format specifiers in the urlString are incomplete, try this.

```
#define urlString @"%@/icancer/webservice_iphone/%@"
```